# Proof that every proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is the proof: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~sjw47/Lecture1-3.pdf, page 2 after Zorn's Lemma.
I stuck on that line:

Now suppose $x_1, x_2$ are in $I$. Then there are $J_1$, $J_2$ in $C$ such
that $x_i ∈ J_i.$

Why there are such $J_1, J_2$?

Answer (score 0):

Because $I$ is defined as the union of $J \in \mathcal{C}$, so any element is in one of them.

Comment: I mean, isn't it possible to get those elements in one $J_i$ then?

Comment: By definition the union $\bigcup_{J \in C} J$ are the elements that are in at least one $J$, so for a pair $x_1, x_2$, there is some $J_i \in C$ such that $x_i \in J_i$ in principle they are different $J$s but since $C$ is a chain, there is some $J_3$ such that $J_1, J_2\subseteq J_3$ and therefore $x_i \in J_3$.